# Titanium Studio Android App does not show up

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

The Android app builds, installs and runs with no errors at all. But upon starting, I am greeted with the Titanium logo (the 'A' inside of the triangle, and on the bottom it says "powered by Titanium"). But I never see the actual app that I am trying to run.
The log shows no errors for me to trace. Not sure why this is happening. Any suggestions as to why this is?

Comment: can you show some code? Sounds like you are running a test app/just starting since you're still using the default splash screen

Comment: I can't show any code, because it's proprietary. But I'm not just starting this app because when I run the same app through the iPad simulator through titanium, the app runs and doesn't show the default splash screen. I'm confused as to why the splash screen is showing when I run it on Android.

Comment: Android pulls the splash screen from a different directory than where the iOS splash screens come from. Ok, so my suggestion is if you are launching the app for android and you are not getting any errors, look for code that is iOS specific and throw an `if (iOS)` around them. I once had the same issue, no error and would not launch. Turns out I had something like: `var win1 = Ti.UI.iOS.createNavigationWindow();` and once I threw an `if (iOS)` around it, it worked. In fact I have a sticky note still attached to my monitor that has this noted.

Comment: Please leave an answer so I can give you the points. Thanks.

Comment: Did that work though? lol

Comment: lol no... There were a lot of if statements to make and to check the OS. Thinking that it would have work, it didn't. It's still the same thing.

Comment: has this app ever worked in android?

Comment: No it hasn't. I had to deal with lots of errors before. But up until now, it would output lots of errors that I ended up fixing. Now it just runs/installs with no errors, but I'm greeted with a splash page.

Comment: Hmm, well I can't do much without looking at some code. If you want to email me, I can offer more help: ronnieswietek@gmail

Comment: Change your Application Id in tiapp.xml and then try to run.

Comment: @Murtz that did not work